# Percentage in relation to users reported before they played 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the percentage of users reported before they played 3 games. The tables I have are Reports with offender_id and reported_date and Games with account_id and game_date.

I thought trying

```
SELECT offender_id
     , reported_date 
  FROM Reports
WHERE offender_id in (SELECT account_id 
            FROM Games 
      HAVING COUNT(account_id) < 3)  
AND (SELECT game_date FROM Games WHERE game_date < reported_date);
```

But i get no results. Would this approach even show me the accounts reported before they played 3 games? I am forgetting the percentage for now, I just want to be able to show the number of users reported before they played 3 times.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Games is only available in a sub query

Comment: @MayaG have updated, ty